# Changing colour of specific link backgrounds - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, navbar

I have used bootstrap to code a [website](http://hawickhighnews.co.uk) and I am looking to change the background colour of some specific links in the navigation bar.

I have links on the left side which have the normal background colour, but over on the right I have another set of links which I would like to stand out more (i.e have the background another colour).

I am not looking for the hover or active colour to be changed, just the background colour of the navbar in that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to change the whole navbar to the same color you can do following in your css:

```
ul.navbar-right {
 background-color: red;
}
```

Red is just for example. If you want to five every menupoint another color you could do it for every menuitem itself like this:

```
li.menu-item-810 {
 background-color: red;
}

li.menu-item-811 {
 background-color: blue;
}

li.menu-item-812 {
 background-color: green;
}
```

In the future please remember to provide some code to your question so it is easier for members here to help you.

Comment: Thank you. On mobile and other smaller devices when the menu turns mobile friendly is there a way to hide this class so it doesn't occur? On mobile it doesn't display properly and I would just like to hide it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following css classes. Change the value of background-color as per your requirements.

```
.menu-primary-right li.menu-item-810 {
 background-color: red;
}

.menu-primary-right li.menu-item-811 {
 background-color: blue;
}

.menu-primary-right li.menu-item-812 {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following css and it will change it.

```
.menu-item-object-page menu-item-810 {
     background-color: /*color you like*/;
    }
 .menu-item-object-page menu-item-811 {
     background-color: /*color you like*/;
    }
 .menu-item-object-page menu-item-812 {
     background-color: /*color you like*/;
    }
```

Or you put them between  and give them a class you want and do some ting like this:

```
.your chosen class {
 background-color: /*color you like*/;
}
```

The bonus of this is if you put the 3 links within the div you can change the color by changing one line of code.